# How to position my element using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to create something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4acBx.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<article class="article">
  <header class="article__header">
    <h2 class="article__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <time datetime="2037-10-02" class="article__date">Luty 10, 2037</time>
  </header>

  <img src="./img/articles/article-1.png" alt="" class="article__image">
  <p class="article__content">Ut malesuada mauris non eros bibendum scelerisque. Quisque id lorem eget ex dignissim venenatis. Phasellus dictum velit nec purus aliquet, sit amet convallis velit vehicula.  Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec mollis nibh turpis.</p>

  <a href="#" class="article__read-more">Czytaj dalej</a>
</article>
```

I'm really forced to use that structure, so I can use only CSS to position elements.
The problem is that, I don't know how to position the image without changing the HTML structure.

I would use flexbox, if i could change HTML :(
Can you help me? I really have no idea, how do that.

Comment: Can you use js to change html?

Comment: @NenadVracar Already stated to use CSS only

Answer (score 1):

> I'm really forced to use that structure, so I can use only CSS to
>   position elements.

The absolute simplest solution would be like this, using `position: absolute` on the image and a left padding equal to the image size (+ some space, here 20px) on the `article`

```css
.article {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 220px;
}
.article__image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article__header">
    <h2 class="article__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <time datetime="2037-10-02" class="article__date">Luty 10, 2037</time>
  </header>

  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" alt="" class="article__image">
  <p class="article__content">Ut malesuada mauris non eros bibendum scelerisque. Quisque id lorem eget ex dignissim venenatis. Phasellus dictum velit nec purus aliquet, sit amet convallis velit vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec mollis nibh turpis.</p>

  <a href="#" class="article__read-more">Czytaj dalej</a>
</article>
```

Comment: lol I'm so stupid. I have forgotten that, I can use position: absolute. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways
1. Just make the image float:left

check this snippet

```css
img{
  float:left
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article__header">
    <h2 class="article__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <time datetime="2037-10-02" class="article__date">Luty 10, 2037</time>
  </header>

  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" height=150px width=100px alt="" class="article__image">
  <p class="article__content">Ut malesuada mauris non eros bibendum scelerisque. Quisque id lorem eget ex dignissim venenatis. Phasellus dictum velit nec purus aliquet, sit amet convallis velit vehicula.  Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec mollis nibh turpis.</p>

  <a href="#" class="article__read-more">Czytaj dalej</a>
</article>
```

2. Use flex box.Change the markup a bit ,wrap the image and content with div and make display flex to it

check this

```css
article{
  
}

.content{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article__header">
    <h2 class="article__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <time datetime="2037-10-02" class="article__date">Luty 10, 2037</time>
  </header>
<section class="content">
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" height=150px width=100px alt="" class="article__image">
  <p class="article__content">Ut malesuada mauris non eros bibendum scelerisque. Quisque id lorem eget ex dignissim venenatis. Phasellus dictum velit nec purus aliquet, sit amet convallis velit vehicula.  Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec mollis nibh turpis.</p>

  <a href="#" class="article__read-more">Czytaj dalej</a>
  </section>
</article>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would be glad, if i could do this, BUT header [title + time] still is over image :(

Comment: You must close the tag section. Like `</section>` not `</section`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to `absolute` position the `img` inside its `relative`ly positioned parent.

In this case, you could `absolute` position the `img` inside the parent element, `article` (which **should** be `relative` positioned; otherwise, the `img` element would be absolutely positioned relative to the `body`). To all other child elements, a `margin-left` could be applied with a value greater than the `width` of the image.

Sample snippet:

```css
.article {
  /* parent element is attributed relative position */
  position: relative;
}
.article__image {
  /* `img` element is positioned absolute, relative to its parent */
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.article > *:not(.article__image) {
  /* All direct children of parent element `article` except `img` element is given a margin which is greater than the width of the image */
  margin-left: 210px;
}
/* Other element styles for reference */

.article__header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.article__read-more {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article__header">
    <h2 class="article__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <time datetime="2037-10-02" class="article__date">Luty 10, 2037</time>
  </header>

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Amborella_trichopoda_%283065968016%29_fragment.jpg" alt="" class="article__image">
  <p class="article__content">Ut malesuada mauris non eros bibendum scelerisque. Quisque id lorem eget ex dignissim venenatis. Phasellus dictum velit nec purus aliquet, sit amet convallis velit vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec mollis nibh turpis.</p>

  <a href="#" class="article__read-more">Czytaj dalej</a>
</article>

<article class="article">
  <header class="article__header">
    <h2 class="article__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <time datetime="2037-10-02" class="article__date">Luty 10, 2037</time>
  </header>

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Rose_flower01.JPG" alt="" class="article__image">
  <p class="article__content">Ut malesuada mauris non eros bibendum scelerisque. Quisque id lorem eget ex dignissim venenatis. Phasellus dictum velit nec purus aliquet, sit amet convallis velit vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec mollis nibh turpis.</p>

  <a href="#" class="article__read-more">Czytaj dalej</a>
</article>
```